# Убрать клавиатуру при щелчке на свободное место

Tags: android, клавиатура

Как убрать клавиатуру при щелчке на другое место экрана?

Comment: при щелчке уберите фокус поля ввода. Клавиатура сама уберется.

Comment: куда и что прописать, чтобы при щелчке убирался фокус поля ввода?

Comment: куда прописать - в обработчик клика виджета, после клика по которому должна убираться клавиатура.

Что прописать - вызов метода [clearFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()).

Comment: Учтите, что инструкции к android примитивно-недостаточны. Что такое кнопка "Back" - никто не догадается.

Answer (score 10):

Мне кажется это какой-то нездоровый паттерн действий юзера. В Андроид предусмотрен способ скрытия клавиатуры нажатием кнопки "Back" или же в некоторых софт-клавиатурах предусмотрена кнопка скрытия клавиатуры. Кроме того нельзя упускать из виду, что есть девайсы с хардверными клавиатурами. Так что я бы не стал заморачиваться таким велосипедостроительством. Если это ваша личная инициатива - забудьте о ней, если хотелки заказчика, то попробуйте объяснить ему что в экосистеме Андроида так не принято делать - покажите ему альтернативы. Если заказчик все равно хочет - установите ему клавиатуру с кнопкой скрытия. Если все равно продолжает настаивать то тогда изобретайте велосипед примерно таким макаром:

1. Определите что такое *"другое место экрана"*
2. В этом *"другом месте экрана"* повесьте листенер клика - `View.OnClickListener`
3. По событию клика убирайте фокус `EditText.clearFocus()` или просто скрывайте клаву через `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`

Проблема здесь в том, что этих *"других мест экрана"* может быть слишком много и при изменении дизайна придется опять на них вешать слушатели. Альтернативное решение такое:

Надо обрабатывать `Activity.onTouchEvent()` - он вызывается всякий раз когда касание не было перехвачено никаким виджетом/вьюшкой. Далее применяем п. 3. Минус этого решения в том, что скрытие клавы будет происходить только при касании пустого места в `Activity` - то есть опять упирается в определение понятия *"другого места экрана"*

Comment: getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); - работает безотказно :)

Comment: Listener работает, а сам код getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN) не работает! если его поставить в onCreate загружается и прячет клавиатуру, но в слушателе не работает. Может быть эмулятор глючит фиг пойми в общем...

Comment: GetWindow прям безотказно-безотказно работает:
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(182): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'getWindow' Друзья, пишите, пожалуйста, подробную справку. В каком, например, модуле живет этот самый GetWindow. А то, вроде ответили что-то, галочку себе в карму записали, а пользы от такого ответа нет.

Comment: @Евгений речь не о Delphi, если вы не обратили внимание.

Answer (score 2):

Для скрытия клавиатуры по нажатию на любое место на экране, кроме текстовых полей нужно переопределить метод

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
                v.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```