# Как скрывать клавиатуру по клику на экране?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как скрывать клавиатуру по клику на экране, вне клавиатуры? Реализация скрытия клавиатуры по выходу из textView - не совсем нужный метод.
Похожий вопрос был. Но мне кажется что это не очень "изящное" решение

[Как скрывать клавиатуру при нажатии вне её области?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669615/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

P.S. у меня активити и два фрагмента, на которых расположены основные элементы интерфейса. Активити "пустое"

Comment: как вариант можно скрывать клавиатуру в  методе активити dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) или повесить слушатели на декорвью. Сам метод скрытия -- в ссылке, которую Вы привели

Comment: а есть какой-то метод чтобы при тапе на пустом месте экрана (получается что на фрагменте) на фрагмент и повесить функцию скрытия клавиатуры?

Comment: не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете в виду под "пустым" местом. Если у Вас что-то отображается на экране (сам экран) --значит есть вью. на эту вью вы можете повесить слушатель или переопределить ее диспатч метод. Выбор места зависит от кода и требований когда конкретно клавиатура должна скрываться и перехватываются ли клики или тачи, ранее выбранного Вами места.  попробуйте все-таки в активити переопределить dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev). не забудьте только вернуть значение супер метода

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Убрать клавиатуру при щелчке на свободное место](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/250093/%d0%a3%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: @mvs , пустое место - это любая область экрана кроме textEdit. Подскажите что это за супер метод, значение которого надо вернуть?

Comment: @Vadik попробую код на java переделать на kotlin из второго ответа, тогда смогу сказать дубль или не дубль.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        hideKeyboard();
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

Comment: по-моему мой опубликованный ответ как раз возвращает значение супер метода - `return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)`

Comment: @jurvrn Вы задавали вопрос и я дал ответ раньше чем был опубликован Ваш ответ. и да, в нем вызывается метод супер класса на возврат. цепочка событий нарушена не будет

Comment: я это и имел в виду что на основании именно вашего ответа я понял что нужно сделать. С вашей помощью. Просто вашему  комментарию статус ответа не сделаешь. Но сделаю пометку на вас )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите id для корневого контейнера в вашей разметке:

```xml
android:id="@+id/root_container_view"
```

Повесьте `OnTouchListener` на корневой контейнер:

```kotlin
rootContainerView.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
    if (event.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
        val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
    false
}
```

Игнорируйте ворнинг:

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```

Comment: в дубле вопроса который вы указали снимался ещё фокус с textEdit, у вас нет. То есть это не важно. Тогда ваш код "изящнее"

Comment: а warning там на что будет?

Comment: ворнинг на то, что нужно при переопределении данного слушателя, думать и о кликлистенере. но это можно прочитать и в самом ворнинге. В примере выше, возвращаемое значение false, поэтому он никак не повлияет на диспатчинг события

Comment: @Vadik тут идет скрытие по клику в любом месте экрана, свободного от других View-элементов. Но например у меня есть просто картинки, надписи... пусть и по клику на них скрывается. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

На основе ответа **mvs** - поместил в MaynActivity. Вроде работает как надо.

```
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    currentFocus?.let { currFocus ->
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currFocus.windowToken, 0)
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Comment: @Vadik, или ваш метод через `rootContainerView.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
    if (event.action == ACTION_DOWN) {` чем-то лучше? может быстродействием или конфликтов не будет с другими функциями или вью ?

Comment: все зависит от целей и  остального кода. В случае с листенером --он может быть переиспользован, устанавливаться на определенную вью  и т.п.  Плюс события в нем произойдут если не будут перехвачены раньше. Метод в активити -- находится в активити. в цепочке ивентов первый, если вернуть, не подумав , не то значение -- чилды ивент не получат. для текущей задачи - то-на то. разве что при одной активити и нескольких фрагментах, при диспатче самого кода будет меньше (если конечно фрагменты не от базового наследуются)

Comment: спасибо! фрагменты сами по себе, не наследуются не от кого. Задача просто скрывать клавиатуру чтобы не закрывала экран тапом по любому "свободному" месту кроме текстовых полей Оставлю так как есть.

Comment: Выявился не совсем правильный момент - при тапе на textEdit клавиатура не появляется с первого раза, а только со второго.